# Counting on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+
|store_number|entrance_number|camera_number|
+------------+---------------+-------------+
|          1 |             1 |           1 |
|          1 |             1 |           2 |
|          2 |             1 |           1 |
|          2 |             2 |           1 |
|          2 |             2 |           2 |
|          3 |             1 |           1 |
|          4 |             1 |           1 |
|          4 |             1 |           2 |
|          4 |             2 |           1 |
|          4 |             3 |           1 |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

In summary the stores are numbered 1 and up, the entrances are numbered 1 and up for each store, and the cameras are numbered 1 and up for each entrance.

What I want to do is count how many how many entrances in total, and how many cameras in total for each store. Producing this result from the above table:

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+
|store_number|entrances      |cameras      |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
|          1 |             1 |           2 |
|          2 |             2 |           3 |
|          3 |             1 |           1 |
|          4 |             3 |           4 |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

How can I count on multiple columns to produce this result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with a `GROUP BY` and a `COUNT()` of each item:

```
Select   Store_Number, 
         Count(Distinct Entrance_Number) as Entrances, 
         Count(Camera_Number) As Cameras
From     YourTable
Group By Store_Number
```

From what I can tell from your expected output, you're looking for the number of cameras that appear, whilst also looking for the `DISTINCT` number of entrances.

Comment: Using distinct was the keyword I was missing

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well,

```
DECLARE @store TABLE 
( store_number INT,entrance_number INT,camera_number INT)
INSERT INTO @store VALUES(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(2,1,1),(2,2,1),
(2,2,2),(3,1,1),(4,1,1),(4,1,2),(4,2,1),(4,3,1)

SELECT AA.s store_number, BB.e entrances,AA.c cameras FROM (

SELECT s,COUNT(DISTINCT c) c FROM ( SELECT store_number s, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,store_number) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,entrance_number) + 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,camera_number) c FROM @store ) A GROUP BY s ) AA

LEFT JOIN

( SELECT s,COUNT(DISTINCT e) e FROM ( SELECT store_number s, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,store_number) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,entrance_number) e
FROM @store ) B GROUP BY s ) BB ON AA.s = BB.s
```

Hope it helped. :)